# How to parse a list using simple html dom

Tags: php, html, parsing, html-lists, simple-html-dom

I have an html code, and I'm facing a problem parsing a data out of this html specifically from the part given below:

```
<li id=xyz>
  John Johnson
<sup>1<sup>
","
</li>
```

I want to extract "John Johnson" out of this list and nothing else. Not sure how to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find('text')` is what you're after. It returns all text blocks found in the source.

Based on your example here's a working code:

```
// Test data
$input = <<<_DATA_
    <li id=xyz>
      John Johnson
    <sup>1<sup>
    ","
    </li>
_DATA_;

//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($input);

// >> Long answer
echo "Long answer:<br/>";

// Search all text nodes inside the target node
$search = $html->find('li#xyz text');

// Loop through each node and print it
foreach( $search as $i => $txt ) {
    // No need to specify "->plaintext" since the content is already in plain text here
    echo "$i => " . $txt->plaintext . "<br/>";
}

// >> Short answer
echo "<hr>";
echo "Short answer:<br/>";

// Specifying the index (0th here) returns the Nth element from the array containing all search results
echo $html->find('li#xyz text', 0)->plaintext;

// Clear DOM object
$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Long answer:
0 => John Johnson 
1 => 1
2 => "," 
3 => 
-------------------
Short answer:
John Johnson
```

For more details check the <kbd>[Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Surround the content you need by a  like so.
 is a good option compare to

```
<li id='xyz'>
  <span>John Johnson</span>
  <sup>1<sup>
    ","
</li>
```

Then on your javascript, assuming you are using jquery.

```
var contentToGrab =  $('#xyz span').text();
// just verify you get the data correctly
console.log(contentToGrab);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple javascript you could give a class or Id to the span and grab it from javascript

```
<span id="grabIt">John Johnson</span>
```

And your javascript:

```
Var john=document.getElementById("grabIt").innerText;
```